# Highest Infinispan version for JBoss EAP 6.3

Tags: jboss6.x, infinispan

Can someone tell me what is the highest Infinispan version that I can use with Jboss eap 6.3?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Infinispan 5.2.8.Final** is integrated in JBoss EAP 6.3.
For more details, follow this URL:
https://access.redhat.com/articles/112673#EAP_6

Comment: Do you know if I can use a most recent version? The documentation for this version is limited.

Comment: Since you speak about EAP, you have a supported version. You could try more recent versions and it could work, but you'd lose the support. Why do you want a different version than the officially tested one?

Comment: Because the documentation for the version 5.2.8 es very limited, and the most recent versions have more detailed documentation.